# How to change div content with setTimeout inside of a for loop?

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, settimeout

I have the following code. What I would like the header to do is to change through the different text "Head #" continuously. The code works to change it at intervals, but only once. After the changing is completed, it does not loop and continue the cycle for some reason.

```
<p class="header">Head 1</p>

<script>
    var changeThis = document.getElementsByClassName("header");
    for(i=0;i<10000;i++){
        setTimeout(function() {
            changeThis[0].innerHTML = "Head 2";
        },5000)
        setTimeout(function() {
            changeThis[0].innerHTML = "Head 3";
        },10000)
        setTimeout(function() {
            changeThis[0].innerHTML = "Head 4";
        },15000)
        setTimeout(function() {
            changeThis[0].innerHTML = "Head 1";
        },20000)
    }
</script>
```

Comment: have you looked into the `setInterval()` function/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Andrew_Lohr (and others) for pointing to setInterval. Final Code that I ended up going with for this is as follows:

```
var changeThis = document.getElementsByClassName("header");

var headIndex = 1;

var headTitles = ["Head 1", "Head 2", "head 3", "Head 4"];

function change() {
    changeThis[0].innerHTML = headTitles[headIndex];
    headIndex++;
    if(headIndex > 3){
        headIndex=0;
    }
}

setInterval(change, 5000);
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you would rather be using [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) (runs code every x ms). This stops you from having to define so many setTimeouts in a loop (which can get quite messy)

Here's an example of what I mean, and it will keep looping as you wanted.

```js
var changeThis = document.getElementsByClassName("header");
var headIndex = 2;

function change() {
  changeThis[0].innerHTML = "Head " + headIndex;
  headIndex++;
}

// run change function every 3 seconds
setInterval(change, 3000);
```

```html
<p class="header">Head 1</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval), mind be wary that if you want it to iterate through Head 1, Head 2, Head 3 etc, you might be better off with something like:

```
const elements = ["head1", "head2"...]

let currentIndex = 0
const INTERVAL_LENGTH = 5000

setInterval(() => {
    changeThis[0].innerHTML = elements[(currentIndex++)%elements.length]
}, INTERVAL_LENGTH)
```